# Automatic payout on connected accounts and how to handle verification?

Tags: stripe-payments

I've built an app that charge some money from user A to my stripe account, then when a certain event occur from my stripe account i transfer money to B, then an automatic payout from B stripe connected account to B bank account is scheduled every day.

My question is, how do I handle the fact that the payout could fail if B has not been verified and/or has not provided a bank account?
I tried with webhooks but they seems to work only when the payout fails because of issues related directly to bank accounts and cards, if, for example, I try to make a manual payout with stripe API without B having a bank account it gives me an error on the callback but not on the webhook. What happens if an automatic payout fails because B doesn't have a bank account? Does the webhook get called? How can I test it?

Comment: If user B does not have a bank account, your request to create a payout will simply fail with an `invalid_request_error` --- no payout will be attempted, thus no webhook. In addition to webhooks you should implement some error handling to catch errors that are thrown from the synchronous response to your calls  https://stripe.com/docs/api#errors

Comment: Ok so my best option is to do manual payouts via Stripe API and check if there's an error instead of using automatic payout?